# How to use IGlobalInterfaceTable to pass an interface pointer?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, multithreading, com

- **Without**:

  - MFC
  - ATL

**Question:**

- What are the steps involved, to use [IGlobalInterfaceTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms678517(VS.85).aspx), when **passing** a particular **interface pointer** to **several threads** using [CreateThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682453(VS.85).aspx)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms678517(VS.85).aspx) covers it rather well.
Call RegisterInterfaceInGlobal to put your COM interface in the GIT, pass its cookie to your other threads, which can then call GetInterfaceFromGlobal using that cookie to get the original interface.

Note that each thread has to call CoCreateInstance(CLSID_StdGlobalInterfaceTable... but don't worry, they all get an interface pointer to the same instance of the GIT.