# How to determine the threading model of a COM object you didn't declare or CoCreate

Tags: c++, multithreading, shell, winapi, com

Let's say you're creating an in-process shell extension, and at a certain point you obtain the `IShellItemArray` representing the current folder selection. Or more specifically, you have an `IFolderView2` pointer (`m_pfv2`), and -- on the main UI thread -- you obtain the `IShellItemArray` pointer (`psia`) like so:

```
HRESULT hr;
CComPtr<IShellItemArray> psia;
hr = m_pfv2->GetSelection(FALSE, &psia);
if (FAILED(hr))
    return hr;
// ...
```

And now, hypothetically, you'd like to do some stuff with the `IShellItemArray` on a background thread.

From what I understand, the way you access that `IShellItemArray` pointer from other threads depends on the object's threading model.  If I'm not mistaken, you can use it from other threads freely if it's a free-threaded object, but you'll need do some marshaling if it's an apartment-threaded object.

So how do you know what to do?

FWIW, in my testing, I've successfully passed/accessed the `IShellItemArray` pointer on other threads without marshaling, but I don't know if that's necessarily determinative.  Also, FWIW, I've called `CoGetApartmentType` generally within my shell extension (after it's been loaded into Explorer), which appears to return `APTTYPE_STA`.  But again, I don't know if that answers the question either.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: Always marshal. The marshaler is clever and if the object didn't need to be marshaled in the first place, then the unmarshal will just give you the original pointer back. RoGetAgileReference is a handy helper function that does most of the bookkeeping for you. You call RoGetAgileReference to get an IAgileReference, take the IAgileReference pointer to whatever thread you like, then call Resolve to unmarshal.

Comment: @RaymondChen Okay, thanks.  By the way, my question was inspired by your posts.  So thanks for the information from those, too.

Comment: @user15284017 Or, on systems that don't have [`RoGetAgileReference()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-rogetagilereference), there is [`IGlobalInterfaceTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nn-objidl-iglobalinterfacetable) which can accomplish the same task.

Comment: By the way, can those be used for multiple background threads, or just one?

Comment: And does this mean the background thread(s) must call `Co­Initialize­Ex`?

Comment: Once you create an agile reference, you can take it to as many other threads as you like. Each thread does a Resolve and uses the result.

Comment: One last question: in [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9190/Understanding-The-COM-Single-Threaded-Apartment-Pa) CodeProject article, in the section titled "The Message Loop," it suggests that proxies and stubs are automatically used when a COM object is created on a UI thread.  Am I interpreting that correctly?  So is that article wrong?

Comment: @RaymondChen re: RoGetAgileReference, so someone finally gave us an alternative to CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceOnIStream ? :-P Been years since I've marshaled COM interfaces to different apartments in-process. That was always the go-to.

Comment: Proxies and stubs are automatically generated by CoCreateInstance when the created object belongs to a different apartment. But clearly COM cannot do anything when you just copy raw pointers between threads.

Comment: Every thread that uses the COM library must be initialized with a call to `CoInitializeEx`. It's the only way to place a thread into the desired apartment. Well, it's the only [reliable way](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130419-00/?p=4613) to do so.

Comment: @WhozCraig `IGlobalInterfaceTable` has been available as a replacement to `CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceOnIStream()` for a LONG time. [How to use IGlobalInterfaceTable to pass an interface pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/581172/). Now we have `RoGetAgileReference()`, which is a similar solution with a different approach.